# Guardar datos de facebook en Firebases en IOS

Tags: swift, xcode

Estoy creando una App que tenga dos tipos de método de inicio la primera seria con correo y contraseña, la otra seria con Facebook.Ya llegue a iniciar sesión con Facebook lo que no se como hacer es guardar la imagen en Storage y los demás datos a databases.Adjunto mi código de la función que realiza el guardado de los datos si se Crea una cuenta que no es por Facebook.

```
func guardarUsuario(){
        // guardar en storage
        let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
        let nombreImagen = UUID()
        let directorio = storage.child("imagenesPerfil/\(nombreImagen)")
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/png"

    directorio.putData(perfil.pngData()!, metadata: metadata) { (data,error) in
        if error == nil {
            print("Se guardo imagen")
        }else{
            if let error = error?.localizedDescription{
                print("error en firebase al cargar imagen", error)
            }else{
                print("error de codigo")
            }
        }

    }

    // guardar en databases
    guard let id = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    guard let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email else { return }
    guard let nombre = nombre.text else { return }
    guard let apellido = apellido.text else { return }
    let campos = ["nombre": nombre,
                  "apellido": apellido,
                  "correo": email,
                  "idUser": id,
                  "imagenPerfil": String(describing: directorio)]
    ref.child("users").child(id).setValue(campos)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Gracias a todos por sus repuestas

Comment: hay diferentes DB que te pueden servir, incluyendo UserDefautls, aunque UD es mas bien para persistir datos pequeños como id, bools por ejemplo, te puede servir Realm() que tienen muy buena documentación, o también SQlite... solamente le pasas los datos al db, y listo ya tendras tus datos guardados en el dispositivo.